# OpenCart 3.0.2.0 vQmod 2.6.3 twig edits not working

Tags: php, xml, twig, opencart, vqmod

I'm having this issue while creating a **vqmod** for editing **order notification/alert for admin**. I've already tried the `**Admin Dashboard Gear Solution**` (to clear the theme cache), but it didn't work. And also, the **`order_alert.twig`** file had repeating lines of text that I added in the vqmod file. It seems that the edited text was added to the vqcache file as many times as I refreshed the modifications cache in the admin panel, but all of that is useless as the final admin order email still has the old template  Anyhow after that I tried the Dashboard Gear Solution and cleared the theme cache and even disabled it but none of that worked. After that, I deleted all the **`vqcache`** files but now even the vqcache files from the **`order alert vqmod`** aren't appearing. Please help. My vqmod version is `2.6.3` and all other vqmods (all created by me) are working fine. There is no **error/conflict** in **vqmod logs** or the **opencart error log**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your other vQmods are working, it sounds like there probably is some error in the one you're working on. Try stripping it down to a very simple vQmod which makes a very small change and see if that works. If so, the problem is some other part of the vQmod.

Comment: Thanks, Somehow it worked after deleting VQMod's cache files, checked and mods cache files. And yes there were some errors too but logical not syntactical.